# Dynamic query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this situation, but i can't resolve it.

Structure DB:

TABLE Elementi

```
id | idElemento | idTipo
1  | 1          | 1
```

TABLE Tipi

```
id | Tipo
1  | Persona
```

TABLE Valori

```
id | idElemento | idInfo | Valore
1  | 1          | 1      | Mario
1  | 1          | 2      | Rossi
1  | 1          | 3      | 0810000000
1  | 1          | 3      | 3330000000
```

TABLE Info

```
id | Info     | Multi
1  | Nome     | 0
1  | Cognome  | 0
1  | Telefono | 1
```

Desired outcome:

```
idElemento | Nome  | Cognome | Telefono |
1          | Mario | Rossi   | 0810000000, 3330000000 |
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you explain what your issue is, please? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the Info table, the ids are the same, seems they should be 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

As alexander commented, info table must have an incremental field (1,2,3) with respect to the information.

You can combine the Telfono using [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functionality.

Since, you want to populate the fields basically from the table *info*. This involves [transpose table concept:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304446/transpose-the-results-of-a-mysql-query)

```
SELECT idelemento
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN t1.info = 'Nome'
                THEN t1.value
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Nome
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN t1.info = 'Cognome'
                THEN t1.value
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Cognome
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN t1.info = 'Telefono'
                THEN t1.value
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Telefono
FROM (
    SELECT idElemento
        ,info.info
        ,group_concat(valore separator ', ') value
    FROM valori
    INNER JOIN info ON info.id = valori.idInfo
    GROUP BY idInfo
    ) t1;
```

Inner query exactly gives the same result without the transposed data. But, I am not sure why you need to populate as fields from the table *info*. But here you go:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78cd6/11)