# SQL - Change column value to rows value

Tags: mysql, sql

l use SQL (Mysql). How to change columns value to rows value?
Here is my query:

```
 select sum(if (tr = 1,1,0)) as 1x,
 sum(if (tr = 2,1,0)) as 2x,
 sum(if (tr = 3,1,0)) as 3x,
 sum(if (tr = 4,1,0)) as 4x,
 sum(if (tr = 5,1,0)) as 5x,
 from
 (select user_id,
   count(subsorder_id) as tr
   from subs_order
   where subsorder_status = 'paid'
   group by user_id)tab
```

Here is the result:

---

```
 1x    2x   3x    4x   5x   
 150  100   75    50   25
```

Expected Result:

Level  Total

---

```
 1x     150
 2x     100
 3x     75
 4x     50
 5x     25
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose the results of a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304446/transpose-the-results-of-a-mysql-query)

Comment: Rather than showing us what your data looks like *after* your attempt (that gives you the wrong results), show us what your data looks like initially. It's much harder for us to tell you how to get from "A-B", when you you tell us you're at "C", and don't tell us where "A" is.

Comment: Although this is likely a duplicate of that as the question is asked, I doubt the OP really needs to transpose their data, @AleksG ; the reason it's been pivoted in the first place is because of their conditional aggregates. Likely this simply needs an additional column in the `GROUP BY` and a single `SUM`expression.

Comment: @Larnu I'm simply going by the OP showing what he got vs what he wants - and it's a simple transposition.  I agree, we need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt is pivoting the results; but you can avoid that, and just determine your custom title using String function [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), and group by on that:

```sql
SELECT
   CONCAT(tr, 'x') AS level,
   COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
 (select user_id,
         count(subsorder_id) as tr
  from subs_order
  where subsorder_status = 'paid'
  group by user_id) tab
GROUP BY level
```